Can tags be used securely in Github for deployment and OIDC?
I have several org repositories that deploy into cloud environments via AWS and OIDC. The typical release process is as follows:

Decide that main is in a state we want to deploy. main is configured with a typical branch protection set up
Cut a release and tag matching v* from main. The v* tag pattern is protected via Github Rulesets to only allow repository maintainers to create/update/delete these tags.
Pushing to a v* ref kicks off a workflow that logs into the OIDC role with ref:refs/tags/v123, which matches the cloud policy so everything is fine.

The issue is that a repository maintainer could technically push a branch with malicious code (say a malicious workflow), cut a tag matching the protected pattern, and be able to assume the cloud role. This is a single point of failure as a single maintainer can take over the cloud role.
Surely there's a way to mitigate against this but I couldn't find anything in the rulesets documentation. Any ideas?

What about ensuring that all changes potentially running workflows with credentials are reviewed before being merged and including maintainers?

@dan1st you could but what is stopping the maintainer from pushing a new workflow without the approval protection?

Configure the approval protection such that it also affects maintainers? I think GitHub has an option to enforce rules for maintainers as well (that rule could be turned on or off by repository admins)
